# How do I attach a node with another node?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am having trouble trying to create platforms alongside a invisible line that is in the middle, I want it to have an SKPhysicsBody so that when passed through by the Hero Character, it increases the score, yet I can't seem to imagine the code the would work, specifically how to create the line with it being in the middle of the platform at all times, especially when the platform decides to move. Any tip would be greatly helpful.

```
                                     |
                                     |
                             ________|_________
                            |        |         |
                            |        |         |
                            |________|_________|
```

Comment: To be sure I understand the question, you want to set up a line for score keeping that follows along with a platform so that if the player passes through the line, they get points or something like that?

Comment: Does the platform need to have a physicsBody as well?

Comment: @CodeMonkey It has a physicsBody to make contact with the player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to implement what you described.

```
- (void) didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    // Show outline of physics bodies for debugging purposes.
    self.view.showsPhysics = YES;

    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];

    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];

    SKSpriteNode *platform = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blueColor] size:CGSizeMake(128, 64)];

    platform.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:platform.size];
    platform.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                                    CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    [self addChild:platform];

    SKSpriteNode *line = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(2, 128)];
    // Line is invisible
    line.hidden = YES;
    // physicsBody of line
    line.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:line.size];

    // Position line...adjust this accordingly
    line.position = CGPointMake(platform.position.x, platform.position.y+line.size.height/4);
    [self addChild:line];

    // Connect nodes with physics joint
    [self connectNode1:platform toNode2:line];

    [platform.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(100.0, 0)];
}
```

This method connects two sprite nodes, at their midpoint, with a physics joint.

```
- (void) connectNode1:(SKSpriteNode *)node1 toNode2:(SKSpriteNode *)node2
{
    CGPoint midPoint = CGPointMake((node1.position.x + node2.position.x)/2,
                                   (node1.position.y + node2.position.y)/2);

    SKPhysicsJointFixed *joint = [SKPhysicsJointFixed jointWithBodyA:node1.physicsBody
                                                               bodyB:node2.physicsBody
                                                              anchor:midPoint];
    [self.physicsWorld addJoint:joint];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's quite detailed and honestly I never thought of using SKPhysicsJointFixed, because I simply never experimented with it.

Answer (score 0):

Make the line a child of the object using the `- (void)addChild:(SKNode *)node` as referenced in the [SKNode Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/addChild:).

If you do not want a child/parent relationship you can tie the line to the object like this:

```
line.position = CGPointMake(object.position.x+10, object.position.y+10)
```

where +10 is any value you need it to be. If the 'object' moves you will have to update the line's position during the `update:` method to keep track with the object's position.

Comment: While I would agree with your answer if it were a single platform, but I generate multiple platforms at various locations and trying to keep track of that, it seems quite inefficient. Really appreciate the answer though!